# Find High and Low between 09:16 to 10:15 am on 1 Minute Time Frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I would like to Find High and Low between 09:16 am to 10:15 am candles on 1 Minute Time Frame using pine script . I m trying but no luck.

```
//@version=4    
study("High-Low", overlay=true)
higeshthigh=highest(high,59)
plot(higeshthigh)
lowestlow=lowest(low,59)
plot(lowestlow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PineCoders' FAQ - "[How can I track highs/lows for a specific period of time?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time)"

and just modify the default timeAllowed input to "0916-1015", directly in the code or from the input settings:

```
timeAllowed = input("0916-1015", "Allowed hours", input.session)
```

[image]